# How do I provide a page template in kotlinx-html?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlinx, kotlinx-html

I would like to generate a bunch of HTML files with kotlinx-html and I want to start each file with the same template. I would like to have a function for the base structure and provide a lamda to this function for the specific content like so (non working code):

```kotlin
// provide block as a div for the sub content, does not work!
private fun createHtmlPage(block : () -> DIV.()): String {
    val html = createHTMLDocument().html {
        head {
            meta { charset = "utf-8" }
            meta { name="viewport"; content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" }
            title { +"Tables" }
            link(href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "style")
        }
        body {
            block {}
            script("", "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js") {}
        }
    }
    return html.serialize(true)
}
```

and use this function like this (again non working code):

```kotlin
private fun createIndexPage(tables: Tables) {
    val indexFile = File(path, "index.html")

    // call my template function with a lamda - does not work
    val html = createHtmlPage {
        h1 { +"Tables" }
        tables.tableNames.forEach { tableName ->
            a("${tableName}.html") {
                +tableName
            }
            br
        }
    }
    indexFile.writeText(html)
}
```

Can anyone point me in the direction how to do this?

**Additional question**

I have found out that project [Ktor HTML DSL](https://ktor.io/docs/html-dsl.html) exists and they have template support on top of `kotlinx-html`. Am I supposed to use this library instead of `kotlinx-html` directly? Is it possible to use it without `Ktor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Ktor. It can be done with just kotlinx-html and plain Kotlin.

### TLDR

Change `block : () -> DIV.()` to `block : HtmlBlockTag.() -> Unit` and change `block {}` to `block()`, so that the final code becomes:

```
private fun createHtmlPage(block: HtmlBlockTag.() -> Unit): String {
    val html = createHTMLDocument().html {
        head {
            meta { charset = "utf-8" }
            meta { name="viewport"; content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" }
            title { +"Tables" }
            link(href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "style")
        }
        body {
            block()
            script("", "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js") {}
        }
    }
    return html.serialize(true)
}
```

So that you can use this function with code like this:

```
val result = createHtmlPage {
    div {
        h1 {
            +"It is working!"
        }
    }
}

println(result)
```

Then the output will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <title>Tables</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="style">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>It is working!</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type=""></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### What's wrong with the code

Your first block of code has this signature:

```
private fun createHtmlPage(block : () -> DIV.()): String
```

This isn't valid Kotlin code, because the type of parameter `block` isn't valid. Instead of using type `() -> DIV.()` it should be `DIV.() -> Unit`. This is a special construct in Kotlin, called a [function type with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types), which allows you to call your `createHtmlPage` function with a lambda, in which the lambda is scoped to a receiver object of type `DIV`.

So the function should be changed to:

```
private fun createHtmlPage(block: DIV.() -> Unit): String
```

The second part that is not valid is this:

```
body {
    block {}
}
```

Because the parameter called `block` is of type `DIV.() -> Unit`, it needs to have access to an argument of type `DIV`. You don't have to pass with argument like in a normal function call, like `block(someDiv)`, but it still needs access to it. But you don't have an object of type `DIV` available in your code, but you do have an object of type `BODY`, which is created by the `body` function. So if you change the parameter type of `block` from `DIV.() -> Unit` to `BODY.() -> Unit`, then you can use the `BODY` object created by `body` function.

So you can change the `createHtmlPage` function to:

```
private fun createHtmlPage(block: BODY.() -> Unit): String
```

and then you can provide the object of type `BODY` like this to `block`:

```
body {
   this@body.block(this@body)
}
```

which can be shortened to:

```
body {
   this.block(this)
}
```

which can be shortened to:

```
body {
   block()
}
```

This last shortening step may be difficult to understand, but it's like this: because `body` function accepts an *function type with receiver* of type `BODY.() -> Unit`, the lambda that you pass to the `body` function, will be scoped to the `BODY` class/type, so that lambda has access to members available in the `BODY` type. The `BODY` type normally doesn't have access to the `block()` function, but because `block` is of type `BODY.() -> Unit`, instances of `BODY` also have access to the `block` function as if `block` is a member of `BODY`.
Because the call to `block()` is scoped to an instance of `BODY`, calling `block()` behaves like calling `aBodyInstance.block()`, which is the same as `block(aBodyInstance)`. Because of this, at this location in the code, you can also call is with just `block()`.

Instead of using `createHtmlPage(block: BODY.() -> Unit)` you could also use `createHtmlPage(block: HtmlBlockTag.() -> Unit)` so that you can use it in other places.

Comment: Works perfekt, thanks for your answer. In the mean time I switched to Kotlin 1.8 and it showed me the error (not valid Kotlin code). When I wrote this code I used an older Kotlin version, which was not able to show me the place of error. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ktor-server-html-builder` library without a server. Here is an example:

```
import io.ktor.server.html.*
import kotlinx.html.*
import kotlinx.html.stream.appendHTML

fun main() {
    val template = LayoutTemplate().apply {
        header {
            +"Ktor"
        }
        content {
            articleTitle {
                +"Hello from Ktor!"
            }
            articleText {
                +"Kotlin Framework for creating connected systems."
            }
        }
    }

    val builder = StringBuilder()
    builder.appendHTML().html(block = {
        with(template) { apply() }
    })

    println(builder.toString())
}

class LayoutTemplate: Template<HTML> {
    val header = Placeholder<FlowContent>()
    val content = TemplatePlaceholder<ContentTemplate>()
    override fun HTML.apply() {
        body {
            h1 {
                insert(header)
            }
            insert(ContentTemplate(), content)
        }
    }
}

class ContentTemplate: Template<FlowContent> {
    val articleTitle = Placeholder<FlowContent>()
    val articleText = Placeholder<FlowContent>()
    override fun FlowContent.apply() {
        article {
            h2 {
                insert(articleTitle)
            }
            p {
                insert(articleText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I recommend implementing your own layer on top of `kotlinx-html` for templating because that's not hard to do and it will solve your particular problem better.